# Body class to each level of a hierarchical custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, css, body-class

How would this be adapted to apply to specific custom taxonomies?

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'custom_cat_archiev_class' );
function custom_cat_archiev_class( $classes ) {
    if ( is_category() ) {
        $cat = get_queried_object();
        $ancestors = get_ancestors( $cat->term_id, 'category', 'taxonomy' );
        $classes[] = 'catlevel-' . ( count( $ancestors ) + 1 );
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `is_tax` instead of `is_category`, and update `get_ancestors` to get taxonomy from the queried object:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'custom_cat_archiev_class' );
function custom_cat_archiev_class( $classes ) {
    if ( is_tax( ['custom_tax_1', 'custom_tax_2'] ) ) {
        $term = get_queried_object();
        $ancestors = get_ancestors( $term->term_id, $term->taxonomy, 'taxonomy' );
        $classes[] = 'catlevel-' . ( count( $ancestors ) + 1 );
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: It works, but I can't update my upvote.

Comment: Never vote in a hurry. +1 from me.